# I would like to click on an <a> tag with only the attribute href="javascript: GFESubmitForm('add-credit-report-quotation-report-details.do')"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium for python, I am trying to submit a form by clicking on a link

I've tried

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='javascript: GFESubmitForm(\'add-credit-report-quotation-report-details.do\')"]).click()

Doesn't work for me, even when I escape the quotes with a '\'

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the Xpath is correct? Maybe post the webpage here so we can check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the website requires a login unfortunately. I screenshoted the pages html and uploaded it here https://github.com/seandk88/selenium-python-project

Comment: Its the only file, if you need any more info please let me know. There is an image inside it which is the 'clickable' area on the screen

Comment: Try this: Right click on the page. Inspect element. Depending on which browser you're using find the "Select an element in the page to inspect it" button(which has the cursor over square icon. Click on the button, and it will show the corresponding source in the opened UI. Right click that part of the source and go to Copy -> Copy Xpath. Paste the exact thing on there and try again.

Comment: Also, Please add the error you get after the command fails. It might be just a timed action, do ```sleep(5)``` before the code to check.

Comment: I think it was a sleep issue, time.sleep(3) sorted it! Thanks so much

Comment: Oh well in that case i suggest you read up on [this section](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp). You can have ```Selenium``` wait for a certain event (like a button to appear) for a more efficient approach. You can search the web for more help on that.